# Why does jQuery .css('background-color') return rgba(0,0,0,0) for 'transparent'?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a box here - http://jsfiddle.net/U68p3/2/ - with a transparent background.  When I read  the background with jQuery's .css('background-color') it returns

```
               rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

which is not very helpful if my code is looking for a match with 'transparent'.

Why is jQuery doing this and is there a way I can make it return 'transparent'?

Thanks.

```
$(function() {
    var bkgnd = $('#box').css('background-color');
    console.log('background-color is ' + bkgnd);
});
```

Comment: jQuery docs: *Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).*

Comment: Do you actually *need* a textual representation of the color, or are you just comparing it to something else? http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/U68p3/16/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not jquery, the computed value for the color are represented in RGBa (Red, Blue, Green, Alpha - for opacity)  and not in as color names (like red, blue, orange, transparent etc) or as hex values. According to the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) transparency is represented as `rgb(0, 0, 0)`.

> if the value is translucent, the computed value will be the rgba() corresponding one. If it isn't, it will be the rgb() corresponding one. The transparent keyword maps to rgb(0,0,0).

So instead of looking for this specific value you can add a specific css rule just to include transparency and add that class to the element and use `.hasClass` or `.is` of that class to check if the element is transparent.

It seems like different browsers represent it in different ways, IE, FF gives the value as `transparency` so it is anyways better not to rely on this value representation for any logic.

Comment: *"the computed value for the color are represented in RGB and not in text representation"* The `rgb` notation **is** a textual notation. But you're right, it's not jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right i mean (red, orange, transparent etc..) by textual representation

Comment: Also note that the OP's talking about `rgba`, not `rgb`.

Comment: _"According to the specs transparency is represented as rgb(0, 0, 0)."_ Surely you mean rgba(0,0,0,0), since rgb(0,0,0) can only be 'black'.

Comment: @Steve Yeah infact it maps the color to rgb(0,0,0) with an alpha value of 0 when transparent. This is acc to MDN specs. [W3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent-def) the same thing `Fully transparent. This keyword can be considered a shorthand for transparent black, rgba(0,0,0,0), which is its computed value.` [Also   it says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties) `This property sets the background color of an element, either a <color> value or the keyword 'transparent', to make the underlying colors shine through.` So you can look for either of the value

Answer (score 4):

It's not jQuery. jQuery returns what the browser gives it for the computed value (e.g., from `getComputedStyle` or `currentStyle`). What the browser gives it may be in any notation form the browser wants to use. In this case, the browser on which you're testing uses [`rgba`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) (red, green, blue, "alpha" — e.g., opacity, 0 = transparent), which is a pretty good notation. Other browsers may just use `rgb` or even hex color strings, which would be unfortunate as neither of those can represent `transparent` correctly.

Comment: Interestingly i see `transparent` in FF

Comment: @PSL: Yup, there you go -- it depends on the browser.

Comment: So it looks like I need to compare the .css() return string  with "transparent" or "rgba(0,0,0,0)" to determine in any browser that the background is transparent.

Comment: @Steve: At *least* those, yes, and with and without spaces between the `rgba` values.

Comment: Yuk!  I expected more from jQuery.

Comment: @Steve: Maybe they'll get to it someday. :-) Or perhaps you'd like to write it and submit a pull request to the jQuery project?

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to get the color as a name directly from jQuery.

You can instead use the plugin jQuery Color (https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to convert the value to its name, or manually do something similar.

An example using your jsFiddle

```
$(function() {
  var bkgnd = $('#box').css('background-color');
  console.log('background-color is ' + jQuery.Color(bkgnd).toString());
});
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/Ap6qD/1/)