# check and change background color

Tags: jquery, background-color

I want changing background colors, but I can set on red. After red can't work change on blue. If don't return true. I write red - `"rgb(256, 0, 0)"` and still not work. How can I do?

```
if($("#row-"+id).css("background-color")!="red")
{
    $("#row-"+id).css("background-color", "red");
}
else if($("#row-"+id).css("background-color")== "red")
{
    alert("don't show this");
    $("#row-"+id).css("background-color", "blue");
}
```

Comment: BTW correct value of red is `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, not `rgb(256, 0, 0)`.

Comment: use console.log to check what is the value.

Comment: Why are you using "else if"? Just the else should be enough because if it isn't "red" (first if) the in the else it will always be red therefore no second if necessary..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
var $div = $('div');
var bg = $div.css('background-color');

if (bg !== 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
    $div.css('background-color', 'red');
}
else {
    $div.css('background-color', 'blue');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9jYE/

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome $(selector).css("background-color") will return an rgb value.

Therefore you can do this:

```
<p id="row" style="background-color:red">Hello</p>

<script>
  var bgColor = $("#row").css("background-color");

  if(bgColor === "rgb(255, 0, 0)"){
    $("#row").css("background-color", "blue");
  } else {
    $("#row").css("background-color", "red");
  }
</script>
```

However, this is not jQuery specific. jQuery returns what the browser gives it for the computed value (e.g. from getComputedStyle or currentStyle). What the browser gives it may be in any notation form the browser wants to use.

See here: [Why does jQuery .css('background-color') return rgba(0,0,0,0) for 'transparent'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574125/why-does-jquery-cssbackground-color-return-rgba0-0-0-0-for-transparent)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($("#row-1").css("background-color")!="rgb(255, 0, 0)")
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/vU8r4/